# Where to learn about differential operators?

Tags: derivatives, reference-request

I was reading the wikipedia page on [Differential Operators.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator#cite_ref-2).

It introduces the general concept of a differential operator and then it
goes through some examples.

It mentions the derivative, the theta operator, the laplacian, the del operator, what is an adjoint of a linear operator, etc..

I'd like to know if there are some books,resources where these topics are treated in a general, related way.

Comment: I was also interested in this topic but didn't find any reference. Do you have good news? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exactly the same problem for years. I thought this must be a secret (my teachers never tell where they learned from) until I read a series paper by [Achim Kempf](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.0747).

The introductory start can be [Shift Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator) and [Operational Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_calculus).

Bunch of good resources referenced in Wiki pages.

[H. Jeffreys (1927) Operational Methods In Mathematical Physics](https://archive.org/details/operationalmetho029814mbp)

[Marchenko, V. A. (2006). "The generalized shift, transformation operators, and inverse problems"](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-29462-7_8)

...

Comment: @Wombat (and MathArt): Besides these, many elementary ODE (ordinary differential equation) texts have a section/chapter on the very introductory algebraic (i.e. manipulative) aspects of differential operators. Also (for elementary manipulative stuff), see quantum mechanics and quantum chemistry texts. If you have access to a university library, then simply look through the table of contents for such books in the library.